# Using a decorated function as a function's default argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, decorator, python-decorators

Consider this module:

```
#mymodule.py
import logging

def print_start_end(name):
    """
    Decorator that creates a logger and logs the start 
    and the end of the function call
    """
    def decorator(f):
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            logger.info("start")
            res = f(*args, **kwargs)
            logger.info("end")
            return res
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@print_start_end(__name__)
def f(x):
    return x

def g(y=f(3)):
    return y
```

And an example script:

```
import logging
from mymodule import f

logger = logging.getLogger("")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
h = logging.StreamHandler()
h.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(h)

print f(3)
```

Output:

```
start
end
3
```

The decorator is working. But now I write a script to use `g` instead of `f`:

```
import logging
from mymodule import g

logger = logging.getLogger("")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
h = logging.StreamHandler()
h.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(h)

print g()
```

Output:

```
3
```

When executing the statement `print g()`, the call to `f` was successful because it printed the expected return value 3. But why doesn't it also print "start" and "end"?

Comment: It's your logger, I am almost completely certain. The reason I say that is if you add a print statement into the wrapper, you can see it get called for f(3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `f(3)` in `def g(y=f(3)):` is executed only *once*, when the function is defined, not every time when it is called.

Thus, the problem seems to be that by the time `f(3)` is executed in `mymodule`, the logger is not yet initialized. Initialize first, then import, then it works:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
h = logging.StreamHandler()
h.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(h)

from mymodule import g

print g()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the default value is evaluated immediately, *before* the logger has been initialized. The way around this is to defer execution until afterwards.

```
def g(y=lambda:f(3)):
    return y()
```

Comment: But using a `lambda` as the default is strange, too. What if I pass an actual integer parameter? Instead, maybe do something like `def g(y=None): if y is None: y = f(3)`. By using a `lambda` you implicitly change the type of the parameter to 'callable'.

Comment: Sure, that defers evaluation as well.